# Shopify GraphQL: How to add multiple variants to a product?

Tags: graphql, shopify

I'm following the GraphQL [documentation for `productCreate](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2021-10/mutations/productCreate) but I can't figure out how to add multiple variants when creating a product.

I'm using the following mutation:

```
mutation productCreate($input: ProductInput!) {
  productCreate(input: $input) {
        userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
    shop {
      id
    }
    product {
      title
      handle
      variants {
        edges {
          node {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And passing the following variables:

```
{
 "input": {
    "title": "Testing Products",
    "handle": "test-product-2",
    "variants": [
        { "title": "Variant 1" },
      { "title": "Variant 2" }
    ]
    }
}
```

The error I am getting back is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "productCreate": {
      "userErrors": [
        {
          "field": [
            "variants",
            "1"
          ],
          "message": "The variant 'Default Title' already exists."
        }
      ],
      "shop": {
        "id": "gid://shopify/Shop/59898691733"
      },
      "product": null
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "cost": {
      "requestedQueryCost": 12,
      "actualQueryCost": 10,
      "throttleStatus": {
        "maximumAvailable": 1000,
        "currentlyAvailable": 990,
        "restoreRate": 50
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've scoured the internet trying to figure out how to add multiple variants when creating a product on Shopify, but I can't figure it out.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was defining the variants wrong. Without the `options` key (which is odd that it's plural considering it only takes a string?) it wouldn't work.

```
{
 "input": {
    "title": "Testing Products",
    "handle": "test-product-2",
    "variants": [
        { 
        "title": "Size Small",
        "options": "Small"
      },
      { 
        "title": "Size Medium",
        "options": "Medium"
      },
      { 
        "title": "Size Large",
        "options": "Large"
      }
    ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this error today (The variant 'Default Title' already exists.)

What I finally figured out works best is to make sure you specify the options array on the main product. And then also define the options on the variants like so:

```json
{
  "input": 
    {
      "handle": "my-product",
      "title": "My Product",
      "options": ["Size", "Color"],
      "variants": [
        {
          "sku": "1111",
          "title": "My Product Small Green",
          "options": ["Small", "Green"]
        },
        {
          "sku": "1112",
          "title": "My Product Medium Green",
          "options": ["Medium", "Green"]
        },
        {
          "sku": "1113",
          "title": "My Product Small Red",
          "options": ["Small", "Red"]
        },
        {
          "sku": "1114",
          "title": "My Product Medium Red",
          "options": ["Medium", "Red"]
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

If you don't specify the options array on the main product your variants won't have a proper label.